# Am I able to select a range based on a specific string?

Tags: excel, vba, switch-statement, range

I have some working code which finds column 'R', iterates through, and replaces values in different columns (also hard-coded) based on the value in 'R'.  What I would like to is make the script less reliant upon column placement.

I have found and tried a few options haven't been able to come to a proper solution.  I feel I need to use set but not sure how to replace the Select Case("R" & i).Value and other areas where Range is referenced with i.  Ideally, I can replace 'T', 'R', 'F', and 'N'.

Any push in the right direction is appreciated.

```
Sub BackfillUpdate()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    LastRow = Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LastRow
    Select Case Range("R" & i).Value
    Case "Text1"
            Range("F" & i).Value = "Example1"
    Case "Text2"
            Range("N" & i).Value = "Example2"
    Case "Text3", "Text4"
            Range("N" & i).Value = "Example3"
    End Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

EDIT:
The application is one subroutine of many, but this portion is looking at a column for a value,  finding it, and then replacing another column in the same row's value with a specific string based on what it finds. The header name won't change, the string won't change, but the column placement might based on the dataset.

Comment: If your headers are in Row1 (or some known range) then you can use find or Match to locate them.

Comment: I've attempted ad nauseam to use Find, essentially getting stuck at each path taken when trying to recreate the Col + i, alas the effort continues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach....

```
Option Explicit

Sub BackfillUpdate()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, T As Long, R As Long, F As Long, N As Long '<< use some better names...
    Set ws = Sheets("data")

    T = ColPos(ws.Rows(1), "HeaderT") '<< use your actual column header
    R = ColPos(ws.Rows(1), "HeaderR")
    F = ColPos(ws.Rows(1), "HeaderF")
    N = ColPos(ws.Rows(1), "HeaderN")
    'maybe add a check here to ensure all columns were located

    For i = 2 To ws.Cells(Rows.Count, T).End(xlUp).Row
        Select Case ws.Cells(i, R).Value
            Case "Text1"
                ws.Cells(i, F).Value = "Example1"
            Case "Text2"
                ws.Cells(i, N).Value = "Example2"
            Case "Text3", "Text4"
                ws.Cells(i, N).Value = "Example3"
        End Select
    Next i

End Sub

'find a header in rng and return its column number
Function ColPos(rng As Range, hdr As String) As Long
    Dim m
    m = Application.Match(hdr, rng, 0)
    ColPos = IIf(IsError(m), 0, CLng(m))
End Function
```

Comment: This one hits the nail on the head.  Seems simple now that I see it but much appreciated - I have learned something today.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your 'header' row is row 1, you can do the column equivalent of your `LastRow` variable and loop through a range incrementing the column.

Something like:

```
Sub BackfillUpdate()
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    Dim i As Long
    LastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For i = 2 To LastColumn 
        Select Case Cells(1, i).Value 'Starting from "B1" and moving along columns until it finds your value.
        Case "Text1"
            Range("F" & i).Value = "Example1"
        Case "Text2"
            Range("N" & i).Value = "Example2"
        Case "Text3", "Text4"
            Range("N" & i).Value = "Example3"
        End Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

IF your `Case` ranges you're assigning values to need to be more dynamic also, consider looping like above and setting variables for each target column with  `Column` number (i.e - `i`), then another loop using the variables to find your targets and do your thing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the application,  but it may be better for you to put your data into a table.

```
Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As Object
Set ws = activeworkbook.activeworksheet
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("tablename")

Dim rowcount As Integer
rowcount = tbl.ListRows.Count

For i = 1 To rowcount

Dim ColumnName As String ' or integer for index

ColumnName = "header-row-name or Index#"

Select Case tbl.ListRows(i, ColumnName).Value

Case "Text1"
        tbl.ListRows(i, ColumnName).Value = "Example1"
Case "Text2"
        tbl.ListRows(i, ColumnName).Value = "Example2"
Case "Text3", "Text4"
        tbl.ListRows(i, ColumnName).Value = "Example3"
End Select

Next i

End Sub
```

If you want the column name or index to be dynamic, just change the name or create a variable for it and replace ColumnName.